# Determining if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {{1\over \sqrt{n}}-{1\over{\sqrt{n+1}}}}$ is convergent or divergent, justify answer.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find the out if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {{1\over \sqrt{n}}-{1\over{\sqrt{n+1}}}}$ is divergent or convergent.

Here are some rules my book gives that I will try to follow:

[image]

Looking at those I can see that it isn't #1, not a p-series form; It isn't geometric so that rules out #2; #3 looks like a good fit, anyways I don't think the next 5 steps will apply.

Using #3, I'll need to split it up into $a_n$ and $b_n$ so I'll go ahead and combine them into one term: $${ \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} } \over {\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}}$$ And it is at this point that I'm stuck. I need to figure out the highest powers of n in the numerator and denominator.

If I'm on the wrong path I would appreciate some help, otherwise, I just need to figure how to get $a_n$ and $b_n$. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Telescoping series, while not mentioned in your list, are important and I hope were taught to you.

You can write the $N$th partial sum as 
$$
\bigg(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)+\cdots+\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}}\bigg)
$$
where it isn't too hard to see all the terms but the first and last cancel, leaving you with 
$$
1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}}\to 1
$$
as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: Would another way of saying this be "alternating series"?

Comment: no, alternating series are different. I will expand in the above

Comment: Then I have not learned about it yet.

Comment: @DevHeavy it is possible you are still expected to notice it

Comment: I'll try looking it up quickly.

Comment: I see, it hasn't been taught to me yet, but this may be a way to explain it. Maybe we can figure out what this question means together: Please determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {{1\over \sqrt{n}}-{1\over{\sqrt{n+1}}}}$ converges or diverges. Explain your answer.  This is a list of like 50 practice problems that I can do on my own time, but this one doesn't have a solution. Almost all of the other questions end in "justify your answer" so this one may be different.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be taught to you, does it? Why not try to come up with that yourself? Or why not try to understand it now that you've been shown telescoping? It's a simple concept - many terms "cancel" out and not much is left, nothing magical.

Comment: I second what @Kezer said. It is rare that you can actually find a formula for the $N$th partial sum. Here you can and from there it is easy using the definition of an infinite series

Answer (score 4):

**Without recognizing the telescoping nature of the series**, we have

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}$$

Hence, we have

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\right)}\le \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$$

Inasmuch as the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ converges, the series of interest does likewise.

Answer (score 1):

The series obviously converges to $1$ by telescoping the partial sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}
=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$